# Mongodb aggregation max value and keep appropriate another value

Tags: mongodb

I have such docs:

```
{ts: timestamp, X: Y, uid: userid}
```

I want to do something like this using aggregate query:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 {'$group':{_id:'$uid',ts =>{'$max':'$ts'},X: maximised_by_ts_field_X}}
)
```

So, field "X" must contain value X of document which maximized by field "ts".

This can be done in such a way:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
 {'$sort': {ts : -1}},
 {'$group':{_id:'$uid',ts =>{'$first':'$ts'},X: {'$first':'$X'}}}
)
```

But it require additional n*log(n) operations to sort. 
So i want to know some way how to do this without sort operation?

Comment: I think that if there's an index on ts, the sorting step should be pretty fast

Comment: Faster than n*log(n) (n - number of docs)?

Comment: If it uses the index, then yeah. Mongodb uses B-tree indexes, which have a worst case of O(log n) if I recall correctly.

Comment: I think, that return all elements - this is "N" operations with docs. So, sort can't be faster than N. I think get some element - this is require log(N) operations with docs if use index.

Comment: Make a list of N element - not faster than N operations.

Comment: The index is sorted at insert time, not on query time. When an index exists on field foo, and you're sorting by foo, what basically happens is that the collection is traversed following the existing index. If you don't trust it, it should be easy to do a test. Try an expensive query with and without a sort, and do the same with and without an index on the field you're sorting by.

Comment: I think that you absolutely right that index sorted at insert time, so, to get sorted N elements need simply get it, so it use O(N) operations. To perform $group i think need O(N) operations too, so O(N) operations - this is complexity of this query - this is quickly. Thanks.

Comment: But make index by "ts" to perform only this query - this is redundantly, not effective by memory.

Comment: Redundant if you only want to do it once, but if that's the case, why would you even care about the performance of the query?

Comment: My logic say to me that if this value (field X) may be calculated in this query without index why i must to do index? Why not invent how to do this with such query without index?